# Valid download link for Microsoft's Linguistic Information Sound Editing Tool?

Tags: download

Does anyone have a valid link to download Microsoft's Linguistic Information Sound Editing Tool?  I don't want to use C|Net, Softpedia's download link for download.microsoft.com is broken, and I can't find it anywhere on Microsoft's web site.  All I find are help pages on the tool without any reference on where to download it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695928(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: cNet's link to liset.exe is surprisingly malware-free and bereft of their slimy wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the website you cited:

`[Microsoft Agent is deprecated as of Windows 7, and may be unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.]`

So I would guess Microsoft has removed it from their site

Comment: I'd appreciate if someone could tell me why they downvoted this answer?